# How to count and sum inner relational model in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel-collection

I am building a small application in Laravel where I got stuck with the sum of inner relational data,

I have a model `Company` which `has Many` relation `associatedProjects` and `associatedProjects` `belongs to` relation `project` and `project` `hasOne` `technicalDescription`.

**Company** Model:

```php
class Company extends Model {

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Variables\Company\Role', 'company_role_relation', 'company_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function specialisations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Variables\Company\Role', 'company_specialisation_relation', 'company_id', 'specialisation_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function associatedProjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Project\AssociateCompany','company_id','id');
    }

}
```

**AssociateCompany** Model:

```php
class AssociateCompany extends Model {

    protected $table = 'project_associate_company';

    protected $fillable = [
        'project_id', 'company_role_id', 'company_specialisation_id', 'company_id', 'link', 'file_name'
    ];

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Project','project_id','id');
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Company','company_id','id');
    }

    public function companyRole()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Variables\Company\Role',
            'company_role_id','id');
    }

    public function specialisation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Variables\Company\Role',
            'company_specialisation_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Project** Model

```php
class Project extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','koshy_id', 'name', 'slug', 'owner_spv', 'spv_link', 'latitude', 'longitude',
        'landmark', 'city', 'district', 'state', 'pin_code', 'region_id', 'country', 'building_use',
        'sector', 'conxn_id', 'parent_project_id', 'website', 'project_logo', 'tracked', 'verified',
        'code_link', 'status', 'active', 'premium','area'
    ];

    public function technicalDescription()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Project\TechnicalDescription','project_id','id');
    }

    public function associateCompany()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Project\AssociateCompany','project_id','id');

    }

}
```

Now this `technicalDescription` has fields `construction_cost`, now I want to first count total number of `associatedProject` and fetch sum of all the `project`'s `construction_cost` which is in `technicalDescription`, some what I have done this code:

```php
$company = Company:: where( 'status', 'saved')
    ->withCount( 'associatedProjects' )
    ->with('associatedProjects.project.technicalDescription')
    ->get()
    ->transform(function ($value)   {
        $value['project_value'] = $value['associatedProjects']->flatten(2)
            ->pluck('project.technicalDescription')->sum('construction_cost');
        return  $value;
    })
    ->sortByDesc('project_value')
    ->forpage( $request->page , 10 );

$next = $request->page+1 ;
$previous =$request->page-1 ? abs($request->page-1):1 ;
```

I am unable to use `paginate` over here as laravel collection doesn't have such method, moreover the query logic also doesn't appear accurate.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: You want the sum of `construction_cost` per company?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes.

Comment: Please post the three relationships.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `BelongsToMany` relationship to get the `technicalDescriptions` directly:

```php
class Company extends Model {
    public function technicalDescriptions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Project\TechnicalDescription',
             'project_associate_company',
             'company_id',
             'project_id',
             null,
             'project_id'
        );
    }
}

$company = Company::where('status', 'saved')
    ->withCount(['technicalDescriptions as project_value' => function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('sum(construction_cost)'));
    }])
    ->orderByDesc('project_value')
    ->paginate();
```

Comment: I tried this in my code, but I am unable to get response from the controller, No errors is also coming up.

Comment: Replace `->paginate()` with `->toSql()` and post the result of `dd($company);`.

Comment: "select `companies`.*, (select sum(construction_cost) from `project_technical_detail` inner join `project_associate_company` on `project_technical_detail`.`project_id` = `project_associate_company`.`project_id` where `companies`.`id` = `project_associate_company`.`company_id` and `project_technical_detail`.`deleted_at` is null) as `project_value` from `companies` where `status` = ? and `companies`.`deleted_at` is null order by `project_value` desc"

Comment: Does your controller have a `return` statement?

Comment: Yes `return response()->json(['data' => $company], 200);`

Comment: What's the result of `dd($company);`?

Comment: it doesn't give any data, it gets stuck with loading, For your reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG5Zz.png even I don't get any errors too.

Comment: Try visiting the page in the browser.

Comment: `dd(count($company->items()));`?

Comment: Shall I replace `paginate()` with `items()`?

Comment: Put it after `->paginate();`.

Comment: Same problem, no response.

Comment: Do you get a response when you replace `->paginate()` with `->get()`?

Comment: Changed to `get()`, waited for long to check, but still no response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180161/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-and-jonas-staudenmeir).